# Stop form from refreshing but do post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am working on a radio website, with a player, and a bunch of banners where you can click on to play a radio.

The ideal behavior in my opinion would be that if i click on the button to play a radio, it'll jump to the player. But now its refreshing the page, and jumping to the top of the page. which is a bit annoying.

1. I got an form with multiple buttons, those buttons contain the ID of the radio from the database.
2. Then i got my player, without the form being posted, printing a default player, on submit of the form, it'll load all the information needed from the database with the ID that's being posted to the player.

Now my question is, how to stop the form from refreshing and jumping back to the top of the page, while it does post to the player.

if you guys need any code, i am wiling to post it here, but since it a shitload of code on my index.php i need a site where i can put this on.

Comment: Consider using ajax in order to get this done with all necessary requirements.

Comment: use jquery or javascript for click a button and do some event's

Comment: I am not experienced with ajax jquery or Js, so i would appreciate it if you guys could help me out on that one. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use Javascript (and more specifically: AJAX) for this. It may seem daunting, but especially when used in combination [with jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), it's quite doable.

The idea is basically to send requests to a different page *on the background*, without reloading the page, and to use Javascript to update the current page with the newly received information. There are plenty resources on the subject that do a much better job of explaining the details than I could here, but I hope this gives you sufficient keywords :)

Comment: I will have a look if i can find anything, i have 0 experience working with both languages tho..

Answer (score 0):

Web based radio players are usually SPAs (Single Page Applications) because reloading the page interrupts the radio player. That means the page loads only once, and all other content is loaded via AJAX requests that do not require reloading the whole page.

There are several libraries that you can use to achieve this architecture (like Angular.JS for example). Building such an architecture from the ground up with plain JS can easily get too difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use ajax and then call your radio player which is not in form...
Find below example.

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", 
            success: function(result){
                     $("#div1").html(result);
            }
    });
});
```

Hope this wil help.

Comment: And the "button"is the ID or the button name ? and why the url demo_test.txt ?

Comment: is you are using id then use #idOfButton, if class then use .classOfButton

Comment: you can make it generic by using class so on all the buttons this method will call and in data section you can pass selected button's radio station.

Comment: This is just example. you need to pass url whatever you defined in the form action.

Comment: Well im using the ID of the button, because all the button id's are the same, and still no succes. still hops to the top of the page

Comment: first thing is id must be unique for all the elements. if you want same behaviour on multiple elements you can go with class.

Comment: and i didnt define any action, because its all on the same page.

Comment: if you are doing everything in a single jsp then it is bad practice. you should follow some design pattern for the same. but ya to achieve your purpose take another jsp like pass channel number to your radio player.

Comment: So you are pretty much saying, i cant do this if i have all this on a single page, i dont have the time to redo the whole player section, cus it needs to be live soon..

Comment: So your player is also in same page?? i would suggest just take your player div in another jsp n just call that jsp using ajax call and whatever comes into your result just replace that new result with old player div. I think it will be done using this way. You can try this it will not take much time. you just need to add one more jsp and need to call and replace.

Comment: yeah because i load the player through oop php on submit.

Comment: do same thing by using ajax call.

Comment: gonna give it a go, not sure how to use ajax, but i think i'll figure that out.